# p:datatable with scroll on content

Tags: css, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable with primefaces:

```
<p:dataTable var="wapsoplandtl" id="wapsoplandtlList" widgetVar="wapsoplandtlList" value="#{exportController.wapsoplandtls}"
                 paginator="true" rows="50" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="2500px;" styleClass="borderless"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}"
                 currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords}" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50" rowKey="#{wapsoplandtl.dtlsys}">
```

and produce something like this:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, it has scrollwidth attribute, but the header got scrolled to the far right. I want only scroll the content of datatable, not the header and footer (paging). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Add `width: 100%;` to its CSS...

Comment: still same, nothing happens

Comment: @Kukeltje I didn't mean column header, but datatable header. There's word "Pesanan" in the header.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by CSS only, forget about the scrollable attribute of the `<p:datatable>` component, apparently it will always overflow the whole table, and not just the content.

In this case, do the following:

- Remove the `scrollable` and `scrollWidth` attribute from your `<p:datatable>` component;
- Include another CSS class (any name, but keep this name to be used later, in this case I will use the name 'overflow-content') in the `styleClass` attribute from `<p:datatable>`;
- Include the following CSS rule in your page:

-

```
.overflow-content .ui-datatable-tablewrapper table { 
    overflow: auto;
    width: 2500px;
}
```

The result will be something like this:
[image: Datatable]

Comment: Didn't work, scroll is still on the bottom of page and scrolling the whole datatable

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to first add the option `scrollX: true` and should add css to table `width:100%` inline.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "scrollX": true
} );
```

and you are done.

Comment: cannot find css property scrollX

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira its not a css property, you need to add this in the option where you call the datatable funtion https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX

Comment: @PrimeFaces Datatable != 'datatables.net'